# Grid from Bootstrap not working in angular15

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-grid, angular15

I´m trying to make a simple page using bootstrap grid, but for some reason it's not working.

app-component.html:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">test</div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <form (ngSubmit)="retornaGuias()">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Year"
          id="inputAno"
          [(ngModel)]="ano"
          name="ano"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

here is my angular.json:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

and my page is displaying like this:
[image: page in browser]

And when I write in the class just `class="col"` it works normaly.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in nesting your HTML.
The `col-x` elements must be nested inside a `row` and add up to 12 (or else they will wrap).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">test</div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <form (ngSubmit)="retornaGuias()">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Year"
          id="inputAno"
          [(ngModel)]="ano"
          name="ano"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note how `col-4` and `col-8` are on the same level, inside the `row` element.

Comment: I did as you wrote but it still no working.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, from the info you have provided I can not offer more help. Check the dev-tools and see if the bootstrap-style gets overwritten (or is even there in the first place).

Comment: I imported in style.css and it works, thanks to make me think.